# Android начинающим

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток
На следующей неделе собираюсь покупать себе устройство на Android. Естественно заинтресовался в разработке приложений под сию ось. Обращаюсь к знающим людям, с чего начинали? Какие мануалы советуете и т.д. Подскажите, что сможете.

Comment: Дубликат: http://hashcode.ru/questions/46037/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Java. Берите разные книги и учите.
- [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) - ну как без него.
- Мне помогли переведенные [примеры и туториалы](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/).
- Установить подходящую ось для разработки. Как по мне, то линукс наиболее подходящая среда (а иногда - и единственная - например эмулятор GoogleTV есть только под линукс).